# 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't set object of type 'Person' to property of type 'Person'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I have a Job model with the following field:

`@Persisted var assigned: Person?`

Person Model:

```
class Person: Object, Identifiable {
    
    var id: ObjectId { _id }
    
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
       self.init()
       self.name = name
    }
    
}
```

I have a SwiftUI picker to allow a person to be selected, then it's saved to the Job model. This works fine on create, but on update I get the following error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't set object of type 'Person' to property of type 'Person'`

Which doesn't seem to make sense as the error itself states the DataTypes are the same. I have printed them both out and they're identical. What is going on here?

I have tried explicitly casting to person. I'm sure I should just be able to set the field to a new person record.

Comment: I've run into a possibly similar problem. Perhaps you can check here to see if the workaround works for you https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/7435

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. I was getting the chosen Person object from the @ObservedResults I used to populate the Picker:

```
@ObservedResults(Person.self) private var people
```

I swapped that to getting the realm from the existing Jobs Object and then running a query using that realm instance to get the Person record. This result was then added to the Jobs object with no error.